# Magento 2.4.2: Customer unable to reset the password

Tags: magento2

The customer established an account in PMM (Magento) and now can't log in and the "forgot password" instructions don't work - so he says. What's the solution?

Comment: Can you add some more information ? What is the error message when you try to login? If it is something like "The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.", then you can unlock that user by logging into admin with another user credentials and then go to System->permissions->locked users section

Comment: Try checking in private window if it helps.